# is not "My bad?" really 'M I bad, (for "Am I Bad?")

Tags: phrases, expressions

Must we write, "My bad?" instead of the homophonic complete sentence:  " 'M I bad?"  I've always heard the phrase as "Am I bad?" which I show abbreviated previously.  I insist I'm grammatically correct.  Anyone there there agree?  Please don't lower the average even more!

Comment: 'My bad' /mai  bæd/ is not pronounced the same as 'M I bad' /em ai bæd/. But you're right that 'my bad' is not standard grammar. But it is currently an accepted idiom as is. Doing it any other way sounds much stranger.

Comment: One could argue that it’s standard grammar, but that the use of *bad* as a noun is non-standard.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, one would say "my bad" (which is not a question) as a form of light apology. For example, it could be said after bumping into someone. Literally, it is conveying to the other person that you are aware of the fact the thing which is being apologized for (such as bumping into someone) is your fault, and not the other person; i.e., it is *your* bad.

The answer is **no**, you cannot say "am I bad" as a replacement for "my bad" — they are totally different in meaning. One is a question, the other an apology.

Comment: I suppose one could ask "my bad?" as a way of asking if it is your fault, but it seems rather unidiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

**my bad**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/my+bad) is unique in the sense of **culpability**:

> That was my mistake; I admit that that was my fault. Primarily heard
>   in US.